# Richfaces Calendar Minimum and Maximum Dates

Tags: jsf, richfaces

My problem is making the RichFaces calendar restricting the dates to be allowed to be chosen 
by the user.

Let's say I want to allow only the dates of this month and the dates of the next month to be chosen by the user.

I used the preloadDateRangeStart and preloadDateRangeEnd attributes but they did nothing.

I created my own CalendarDataModel which uses the preloadDateRangeStart and preloadDateRangeEnd and enables the items but the calendar on the screen allows only the dates of the current month to be selected. Note that the preloadDateRangeStart is today's date and preloadDateRangeEnd is today's date plus 2 months.

I am missing something here for sure.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `isDayEnabled="isDayEnabled"` attribute, where the value (`isDayEnabled`) is a javascript function you should define, in the form

```
function isDayEnabled(day) {
}
```

See the [richfaces demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?tab=clientSideCustomization&cid=4711323) for more details.

If you want to add validation on the server side, use a custom JSF Validator, or use Hibernate Validator annotations (see richfaces - bean validator)

Comment: Can this be done on the server side?
I do not want to use javascript. I would have to implement extra validations on the server!

Comment: implement the validation on the server manually. Using custom JSF `Validator`. Or, using Hibernate Validator annotations (see richfaces - bean validator)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how it works so here it goes:

I created a class which implements the `CalendarDataModel`.

I did not use the `preloadDateRangeStart` and `preloadDateRangeEnd` attributes though because the `CalendarDataModel` only cares about the range between `preloadDateRangeStart` and `preloadDateRangeEnd` in case you specify them.

My `CalendarDataModel` disables calendar items whose date is out of the date range I specified in a property file and which I use in the `CalendarDateModel` to determine if the item's date is not between the range in order to disable it.

So now it works great. Here is the tag:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="myCal" layout="block">
   <rich:calendar cellHeight="30px" cellWidth="30px" 
       dataModel="#{MyCalendarDataModel}" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="ajax"
       style="width:200px" value="#{MyPage.theDate}"/>
 </a4j:outputPanel>
```

I also tried your solution. It works but it's a bit messy on the client.

Thank you again man

Comment: Could you please post the Java code to your implementation of CalendarDataModel?

Comment: Lazlo I do not have the code. I changed job. Look at the actual implementation http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/JBoss/richfaces-ui-3.1.4.GA/org/richfaces/CalendarDataModelImpl.java.htm and make your changes man. Your name looks like a UUID version 5.